# CGPDFDocumentRef working for some PDF files but does nothing for others

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to convert a single page of a PDF into an image using CGPDFDocumentRef. However, this only works for some PDFs and not others (ex. it works for [this PDF](http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf) but not [this one](https://www.ets.org/Media/Tests/GRE/pdf/gre_research_validity_data.pdf)). What is the difference?

My PDF conversion code:

```
-(UIImage *)pdfToImg: (NSURL *)pdfURL {

    // create CGPDF from URL
    CGPDFDocumentRef pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pdfURL);

    // get reference to page
    CGPDFPageRef page1 = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf, 1); // page 1

    // get size of page
    CGRect pageRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page1, kCGPDFMediaBox);
    CGSize pageSize = pageRect.size;

    // edit DPI
    float dpi = 300.0 / 72.0; // change numerator to increase or decrease dpi
    pageSize.width = pageSize.width * dpi;
    pageSize.height = pageSize.height * dpi;

    // ---conversion process---
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(pageSize);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, pageSize.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, dpi, -dpi);
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    //CGAffineTransform pdfTransform = CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(pdfPageRef, kCGPDFCropBox, CGRectMake(0, 0, pageSize.width, pageSize.height), 0, true);
    //CGContextConcatCTM(context, pdfTransform);
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, page1);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    // ------

    // create image
    UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return resultingImage;
}
```

Thank you in advance!